# multiplicative inverse of rational numbers c++

Tags: c++

My program works fine except when a fraction has a numerator of 0 in the numerator when it does the inverse I get an arithmetic error and it crashes.

I've tried to check for zero int he numerator several different ways but I can't get the program to compile. Can someone give me some pointers.

Here's my code so far:

```
#include <lab58.h>

using namespace std;

int lcm(int u, int v)
{
  if(u == 0 || v == 0)
    return 0;
   else
    return (u * v) / gcd(u, v);
}

Rational rationalAdd(const Rational& augend, const Rational& addend)
{
  Rational sum;
  int lcm = ::lcm(augend.denominator, addend.denominator);

  sum.numerator = lcm * augend.denominator / augend.numerator +
                lcm * addend.denominator / addend.numerator;
  sum.denominator = lcm;

  rationalNormalize(sum);

  return sum;
}

Rational rationalAdditiveInverse(const Rational *rational)
{
  Rational additiveInverse;

  additiveInverse.numerator = rational->numerator * -1;
  additiveInverse.denominator = rational->denominator;

  return additiveInverse;
}

 Rational rationalSubtract(const Rational& minuend, const Rational&  subtrahend)
{
  return rationalAdd(minuend, rationalAdditiveInverse(&subtrahend));
}

// Function rationalMultiply returns multiplier x multiplicand.  The
// result is returned in reduced form.
Rational rationalMultiply(const Rational& multiplier, const Rational& multiplicand)
{
  Rational product;

  product.numerator = multiplier.numerator * multiplicand.numerator;                        
  product.denominator = multiplier.denominator * multiplicand.denominator;

  rationalNormalize(product);

  return product;

}

// Function rationalMultiplicativeInverse returns the multiplicative  inverse.
// The multiplicative inverse, or reciprocal, of a number a is the
// number that, when multiplied by a, yields the multiplicative
// identity, 1.  The multiplicative inverse of the fraction a/b is b/a. 
Rational rationalMultiplicativeInverse(const Rational *rational)
{
    Rational multiplicativeInverse;

   multiplicativeInverse.numerator = rational->denominator;
   multiplicativeInverse.denominator = rational->numerator;

   return multiplicativeInverse;
}
// Function rationalDivide returns dividend / divisor.  The result is
// returned in reduced form.
Rational rationalDivide(const Rational& dividend, const Rational& divisor)
{
  return rationalMultiply(dividend, rationalMultiplicativeInverse(&divisor));   
}
```

Here's the lab58.h file:

```
#ifndef LAB58_H
#define LAB58_H

#include <lab57.h>

using namespace std;

// Function lcm returns the least common multiple of u & v
int lcm(int u, int v);

// Function rationalAdd returns augend + addend.  The result is
// returned in reduced form.
Rational rationalAdd(const Rational& augend, const Rational& addend);

// Function rationalAdditiveInverse returns the additive inverse.
// The additive inverse, or opposite, of a number a is the number
// that, when added to a, yields zero. Thus, the fraction a/b is
// returned as -a/b.
Rational rationalAdditiveInverse(const Rational *rational);

// Function rationalSubtract returns minuend - subtrahend.  The result
// is returned in reduced form.
Rational rationalSubtract(const Rational& minuend, const Rational& subtrahend);

// Function rationalMultiply returns multiplier x multiplicand.  The
// result is returned in reduced form.
Rational rationalMultiply(const Rational& multiplier, const Rational& multiplicand);

// Function rationalMultiplicativeInverse returns the multiplicative inverse.
// The multiplicative inverse, or reciprocal, of a number a is the
// number that, when multiplied by a, yields the multiplicative
// identity, 1.  The multiplicative inverse of the fraction a/b is b/a. 
Rational rationalMultiplicativeInverse(const Rational *rational);

// Function rationalDivide returns dividend / divisor.  The result is  
// returned in reduced form.
Rational rationalDivide(const Rational& dividend, const Rational& divisor);

#endif
```

Lab57.h:

```
/*
 * Prototypes for operations on rational numbers.
*/

#ifndef LAB57_H
#define LAB57_H

#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

typedef struct
{
  int numerator;
  int denominator;
} Rational;

// Function rationalValid returns true if rational represents a valid
// rational number and false otherwise.
bool rationalValid(const Rational& rational);

// Function rationalNormalize reduces rational to lowest
// terms. Negative rationals should be manipulated so that the
// minus sign goes with the numerator.  Zero is represented by zero
// (0) as the numerator and one (1) as the denominator.
void rationalNormalize(Rational& rational);

// Function rationalInput initializes rational from input stream in
istream& rationalInput(istream& in, Rational& rational);

// Function rationalOutput writes rational to output stream out in the
// format rational.numerator/rational.denominator
ostream& rationalOutput(ostream& out, const Rational& rational);

// Function gcd returns the greatest common divisor of u & v
int gcd(int u, int v);

#endif
```

Lab57main.C:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <lab57.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  Rational rational;

  while (rationalInput(cin, rational))
 {
    if (rationalValid(rational))
 {
   rationalOutput(cout, rational);
   cout << " = ";
   rationalNormalize(rational);
   rationalOutput(cout, rational);
   cout << endl;
 }
  else
  {
    rationalOutput(cout, rational);
    cout << " is invalid " << endl;
  }
 }

 return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Don't dual tag with C and C++ when your question is about C++.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read up on how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]).  We can't see your `<lab58.h>` header; it would certainly help if we could.  When the numerator is zero, there is no multiplicative inverse; you end up dividing by zero.  You also mention you can't compile but claim you get a runtime error — that's not entirely consistent.  What is your problem?  What is the test code that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Ok, if I don't do anything to check for zero in the numerator my program compiles and runs until the data set that my professor has provided enters a fraction with a zero numerator so I get a divide by zero error. If I try to insert code to check for zero I start getting compiler errors.

Comment: If you get compiler errors when you insert code, that means you are not inserting appropriate code.  If you insert appropriate code, you will not be getting compilation errors.  What do you plan to do when you get a zero input?  What are you supposed to do when you get a zero (numerator) in the input?  Raise an exception?  Report an error?  Simply return 0 anyway?  Simulate infinities?

Comment: Thanks for including `lab58.h`. Unfortunately, it includes `lab57.h` — and we don't have that, so we can't compile the code you show. Maybe you'd better show us the amended code that won't compile, along with the error messages you get. The whole point of an MCVE is that those helping you can see what you've got and what's going wrong. As yet, we haven't got a `main()` program, or the complete set of headers. Does your tutor provide you with the `main()`, or take your code and run it in their own test harness? If so, it is part of a reason for not having a `main()`, but you should say so.

Comment: He provides the main() and the .h headers. If I provided the lab57.h it would include a lab56.h I'm afraid. It's one lesson stacking on another. I've tried if statements such as if(rational.numerator == 0) return 0; but I get a type conversion error when I try to compile.

Comment: How do you test without your own main?  And the recessive headers make sense for the course but make it really hard to help you.  Not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Using puTTy to access the school's unix system. Using g++ to compile, link and run the program.

Comment: @Ambrus You probably get a type conversion error because you can't construct a `Rational` with a "simple" value like a `0`.  You need to post the `Rational` class.

Comment: Off topic: remove `using namespace std;` for .h files

Comment: What do you want to happen when multiplicativeInverse is called with zero numerator? Please show relevant code.